# SUMIFS not picking up multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I have this formula `=SUMIFS(EffortPC,TaskCode,$B$56&"."&B57,PostingDate,"<="&DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),DAY($A$1)),PostingDate,">"&$A$1-DAY($A$1)+1-WEEKDAY($A$1-DAY($A$1)+2)+1,FeesOrExp,{"Disbursements","Subconsultants"})`.

The last criteria, FeesOrExp, I want to pick up both Disbursements AND Subconsultants but right now it only picks up Disbursements. Am I missing something in order for it to pick up both?

Comment: Wrap it in `=SUM(..)`

Comment: also `DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),DAY($A$1))` is not needed, just do `$A$1`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much. Worked great.